# Query to compare the first part and load conditionally the second of the values in a column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table1

| code | title |
| --- | --- |
| 11-1011-00 | Main category 11-1011-00 |
| 11-1011-01 | Subcategory 11-1011-01 |
| 11-1012-00 | Main category 11-1012-00 |
| 11-1012-01 | Subcategory 11-1012-01 |
| 11-1012-02 | Subcategory 11-1012-02 |
| 11-1012-03 | Subcategory 11-1012-03 |
| 12-1081-00 | Main category 12-1081-00 |
| 12-1081-01 | Subcategory 12-1081-01 |
| 12-1081-02 | Subcategory 12-1081-02 |

Field1 loads all "title" that their code values end in '00' (Main category).

I need Field2 to load all "title" that their corresponding "code" values end in > '00' (Subcategory).

The logic (that doesn't load data in Field2) is

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT x.`title` 
FROM 
  `#__t1` AS x 
  LEFT JOIN `#__t1` AS y ON x.`title` = y.`code` 
WHERE 
  y.`title` = '[Field1]' 
  AND left(
    y.code, 
    char_length(col)-2
  ) = left(
    x.code, 
    char_length(col)-2
  ) 
  AND right(x.code, 2) > '00' 
ORDER BY 
  x.`title` ASC
```

In other words,

Following Field1 value

If left(y.code, char_length(col)-2) = left(x.code, char_length(col)-2)

Then right(x.code, 2) > '00'

or even more simple load in Field2 all the related to Field1 Subcategories.

Example as follows

| Field1 | Field2 |
| --- | --- |
| Main category 11-1011-00 | Subcategory 11-1011-01 |

| Field1 | Field2 |
| --- | --- |
| Main category 11-1012-00 | Subcategory 11-1012-01 |
|  | Subcategory 11-1012-02 |
|  | Subcategory 11-1012-03 |

Comment: *that doesn't work* is not an error description

Comment: I have corrected it. Hope its more clear now

Comment: ```.. ON x.`title` = y.`code` ..``` Your sample data does not contain matching rows.

Comment: @Akina Edited the post to show desired outcome in simple words. MariaDB 10.8.3

Comment: @Akina Edited post, hope it is ok. Tried to match rows but still no luck

Comment: @Akina Edited again because both Field1 and Field2 load the title not the code

Comment: Why 'Main category 12-1081-00' and its subcategories are not present in desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.title Field1, t2.title Field2
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.code, '-', 2) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.code, '-', 2)
             AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.code, '-', -1) = '00'
             AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.code, '-', -1) <> '00'
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

PS. The effectiveness of this query is low...

Comment: One more question, what would be the syntax in case the `code` was in this format 11-1011.00? Note: Instead of two - there are one - and one .
I tried but it doesn't work with .
Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I have found it! `'.', 1`